# How to change behavior on Splunk imports from Azure logs using MS Splunk Add-on

Tags: azure, splunk

I have some webjobs set up and deployed to Azure, and System.Diagnostics.Trace output is automatically uploaded to (blob db)/(service name)/(year)/(month)/(day)/(hour)/(instance-id)-(pid).applicationLog.csv.

I have the MS Splunk add-on reading these blobs, as per here:
        http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/AddOns/released/MSCloudServices/Configureinputs5

The import works fine, so now I am looking for a way to change the default behavior in a few ways:

1. Splunk reports the source of the data as the full blob name, eg "MyService/2017/07/15/1234-5678.applicationLog.csv"

Desired:  Splunk reports the source of the data just the service name, eg "MyService". This will make searching on source easier

2. Splunk reports the host for the data as the host Splunk is installed on

Desired:  Splunk reports the host as (instance-id), which is in the imported file's name and inside each row in the file.

3. (This is the most important one!)  Splunk reports the Time of the data as the time it was imported to Splunk via the add-in.

Desired: Splunk reports the Time as given by when the log was made; this value is in the payload of the .csv file

Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1.. Why would you want to change the source location? Splunk best practices call for the entire path to be in the source, a better approach to searching would be to specify the sourcetype.. If you were really bent on changing the source then you could use `host_segment`. This can be done in `inputs.conf` on the forwarder.

https://answers.splunk.com/topics/host_segment.html

Question 2.. You can override any host values by editing `inputs.conf` on the forwarder machine. `opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local` takes precedence over all other paths and should be avoided. A better place would be `/opt/splunkforwader/etc/apps/search/local`. After modifying the `inputs.conf` in there and restarting splunkd, you should see the changes take affect

Question 3.. What kind of data is this? Are you streaming network traffic directly to Splunk or forwarding log files? If the latter, do those log files have correct dates and time associated with them? If so then you need to modify your `props.conf` on your indexers to identify the timestamp.